# "continue" and "break" for static analysis

Tags: c, static-analysis, break, continue

I know there have been a number of discussions of whether break and continue should be considered harmful generally (with the bottom line being - more or less - that it depends; in some cases they enhance clarity and readability, but in other cases they do not).

Suppose a new project is starting development, with plans for nightly builds including a run through a static analyzer. Should it be part of the coding guidelines for the project to avoid (or strongly discourage) the use of `continue` and `break`, even if it can sacrifice a little readability and require excessive indentation? I'm most interested in how this applies to C code.

Essentially, can the use of these control operators significantly complicate the static analysis of the code possibly resulting in additional false negatives, that would otherwise register a potential fault if break or continue were not used?

(Of course a complete static analysis proving the correctness of an aribtrary program is an undecidable proposition, so please keep responses about any hands-on experience with this you have, and not on theoretical impossibilities)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This kind of question fits better in programmers(programmers.stackexchange.com) forum rather than in stackoverflow i think ...

Comment: From my [limited] experience, programmers SE doesn't usually provide the same detailed, technical responses as does SO, which is why I figured SO would be a better option. Is there a way for my to migrate this over there, rather than just cross-posting?

Answer (score 2):

My immediate reaction is that the hoops you'd have to jump through to avoid `break` and `continue` would probably hurt the code overall, and make static analysis (or much of anything else) considerably more difficult.

It'll depend a bit on the exact sort of code you're dealing with though. Just for example, if you have something that would really be best implemented as a `switch` statement, a prohibition against `break` would essentially force you to use nested `if`/`else`s which would make the code much more difficult to analyze correctly, and depending on the circumstances, would be very likely to negatively impact the output code as well.

Comment: Many nested `if`/`else`s might take more time for a human to parse, but I would assume that it is much simpler for a static analyzer?

Comment: @B.VB.: If you were writing your own static analyzer, it would probably be a bit simpler if you left out some language features, yes. For an existing static analyzer, it's unlikely to make any real difference. If you did want to simplify the language, these probably wouldn't be the right place to start though.

Comment: +1. If you're writing your own static analysis tool and want to simplify C++ to make your (other) job easier, why not deprecate classes, functions, and all the other features that require more work for implementation? Use an existing tool and don't cut off your right arm to help your left.